# ¿Cómo puedo calcular un elemento del triángulo de Pascal?

Tags: java, bluej

estoy haciendo ejercicios de recursividad en java y me he topado con este:
"En un triángulo de Pascal, como se puede observar en el ejemplo de la siguiente figura, cada elemento es la suma de los dos elementos situados sobre
él, excepto el primero y último de cada fila que valen 1.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Escribir un método de clase recursivo que devuelva el i-ésimo elemento
de la fila f de un triángulo de Pascal; su cabecera será entonces del tipo
public static int trianguloPascal(int f, int i)."

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public static int trianguloPascal(int f, int i){
  if(f == 1){
    return 1;
  }else{
    trianguloPascal(f - 1, i);
    
  }
}
```

Lo que trato de hacer es llegar al caso base que es cuando f vale 1 y devolver el valor del elemento de esa fila, en este caso 1. Pero no sé cómo calcular los elementos de las filas restantes.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Sería excelente si pudieras adjuntar un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) del código en la pregunta. Para familiarizarte con el sitio, puedes leer ["Cómo preguntar"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) y hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender cómo funciona.

Comment: Vale, ya está. No lo había puesto porque es muy cortito y pensaba que no era relevante ponerlo. Gracias por mandarme los enlaces.

Comment: En [esta pregunta](/q/426579/problema-con-el-tri%c3%a1ngulo-de-pascal-en-c) (aunque está en C) ya podés ver una lógica similar a la que buscás. Es cuestión de buscar ;)

Comment: padaleiana el ejemplo que citas es una solución iterativa sobre el problema, no recursiva. Al menos yo, no encontré ninguna referencia en SO en español sobre este úlitmo enfoque en particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como usualmente sucede en los problemas de recursividad, muchas veces el mayor desafío es encontrar las **condiciones correctas de corte**.

## Condición de corte

En nuestro caso sabemos que la recursividad se detendrá (devolver `1`, los casos *triviales*) bajo tres condiciones (pueden ir juntas, por claridad las he separado)

- Cuando la fila sea la `0` *(la primera)* entonces evidentemente el elemento a retornar es `1`.
- Cuando en una fila dada, sea *la primer columna* `(i == 0)` entonces el elemento a retornar es `1`.
- Cuando en una fila dada, sea *la última columna* `(i == f)` entonces el elemento a retornar es `1`.

## Recursividad

Mirando la figura, es rápido suponer para los casos no triviales, que la definición del elemento es la suma de la `i-ésima` posición de la fila superior, más la `i-ésima - 1`, siempre. Sabemos que la "fila de arriba" se representa como `f-1`. Entonces la llamada recursiva sería algo así como

```
return trianguloPascal(f-1, i-1) + trianguloPascal(f-1, i)
```

## Código final

```
public static int trianguloPascal(int f, int i){
    if(f == 0) { // Si es la fila 1, el elemento es 1
        return 1;
    }
    if(i == 0) { // Si es el primero de la fila, el elemento es 1
        return  1;
    }
    if(f == i) { // Si es el último de la fila, el elemento es 1
        return  1;
    }
    // Usando guard clauses, si llegó hasta acá es porque no es un caso trivial, toca calcular
    return trianguloPascal(f-1, i-1) + trianguloPascal(f-1, i);   
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya lo entiendo :)